# Google App Engine Datastore Storage Default Path

Tags: google-app-engine, path, local-storage, google-cloud-datastore, development-environment

What is the default Windows `path` for data from Google App Engine datastore? I am curious as to where this data is being kept on my laptop during devserver.py.

Comment: For future Linux visitors: I found mine in `/tmp/appengine.app-id.username/datastore.db`

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, the default datastore path is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine.<appid>\`.  This directory contains several files, most notably `datastore.db` for the simulated Datastore data.

You can tell `dev_appserver.py` to use a different path by specifying the `--datastore_path` command line arugment.  (See `dev_appserver.py --help`.)